# Validate email with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, forms

I have `input name="email"` and a `button` on the page.

How do I validate this input in live for a valid email address? And add some class for a button, class "active" if it is valid or "inactive".

This is a small task, so I don't want to use a plugins.

Thanks

Comment: The fact that it is a small task is no reason not to use a well-tested plugin that will save you time. http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation#Validate_forms_like_you.27ve_never_been_validating_before.21

Comment: @Chris - using a plugin to validate a single field (that doesn't need validation anyway) doesn't make sense. 
@Steve - the best way to validate an email address is to send an email to it. Using a regular expression (or any other kind of parsing) is unreliable and not worth doing.

Comment: Using jQuery Validade plugin is very easy http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I usually use this javascript function to validate in frontend:

```
function validateEmail(email) 
{ 
 var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/ 
 return email.match(re) 
}
```

it returns true or false.
But anyway, you shouldn't usually only validate sensitive data in the frontend, but also on the server side.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#email').bind('keyup', function(){
    if(this.value.test([REGULAR_EXPRESSION])
        //doStuff -- add active class
    else
        //doOtherStuff -- add inactive class
});
```

replace [REGULAR_EXPRESSION] with one of the regular expressions found here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: Something like `var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;`

Comment: Unfortunatly most of the regular expressions you find for email are wrong. Top level domains aren't limited to four charachters. + is a valid charachter in an email address.

Comment: `this.value` will return a string, `test()` is a method of a RegExp, not of String so it should be `regExp.test(this.value)`.

Answer (score 0):

i used this for mail validation 
**javascript mail code**

```
    function ValidateEmail(inputText)
    {
    var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
    if(inputText.value.match(mailformat))
    {
    document.form1.text1.focus();
    return true;
    }
    else
    {
    alert("You have entered an invalid email address!");
    document.form1.text1.focus();
    return false;
    }
  }
```