# How check if email element is valid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, livevalidation

I use **LiveValidation plugin** (http://livevalidation.com). I need validate one input and if it is ok, make same ajax. Instead submit button I have img and I would like to process it by onClick action. Everything works validation works live, but when I click on image I need to check if is email fill and valid. Is some method like isValid or how can I do it and avoid to process ajax always after click?

```
<input id="email" type="text" name="email" />
<img id="sendToEmail" src="send.png" />

<script type="text/javascript">
var email = new LiveValidation('email', { validMessage: ' ', wait: 500 } );
email.add( Validate.Presence, { failureMessage: "Is required" } );
email.add( Validate.Email, { failureMessage: "Must by email" } );

$('#sendToEmail').click(function() {
  if (email.isvalid) {
    //ajax calling
  }
})
</script>
```

**This is right solution**

```
if (email.validate()) {
  // some process if is validated
}
```

Comment: see this answer - frontend validation for email what you can use to check before you allow any follow actions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5778844/532102

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
 $(function(){
    $('#sendToEmail').click(function(){
        if ( !email.validationFailed ){
           //ajax calling
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: But I use that **plugin**, which validate live and I would like to do whith that.

Comment: I use that normally, but in this specific case I want submit by click on image. Action which would follow I would allow when input is validated. But I don't now how I find out that. It's not anything like **isValid** function there.

Comment: please see updated answer. this is the inbuilt value for checking the validation

Comment: Sorry @Tim I don't know how you mean it. Your example is not using plugin and second example doesn't work in my specific way. How can I use your example with plugin.

Comment: It doesn't help. `!email.validationFailed` is always true